# is GHC's implementation of Haskell semantically broken?

Tags: haskell, semantics, ghc

I noticed something interesting this morning that I wanted to ask about to see if it is in anyway significant.

So in Haskell, undefined Semantically subsumes non-termination. So it should be impossible to have a function

```
isUndefined :: a -> Bool
```

as the semantics would indicate that this solves the halting problem.

However I believe that some of GHC's built in functions allow this restriction to be "fairly reliably" broken. Particularly catch#.

The following code allows undefined values to be "fairly reliably" detected:

```
import Control.Exception
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Unsafe.Coerce

isUndefined :: a -> Bool
isUndefined x = unsafePerformIO $ catch ((unsafeCoerce x :: IO ()) >> return False) ((\e -> return $ show e == "Prelude.undefined") :: SomeException -> IO Bool)
```

Also, does this really count, as you will have noticed it uses several "unsafe" functions?

Jules

EDIT: Some people seem to think that I claim to have solved the Halting problem XD I'm not being a crank. I am simply stating that there is a rather severe break in the semantics of undefined in that they state that a value of undefined should be in a sense indistinguishable from non-termination. Which this function sort of allows. I just wanted to check if people agree with this and what people think of this, is this unintended side effect of the addition of certain unsafe functions in the GHC implementation of Haskell for convenience a step to far? :)

EDIT: fixed the code to compile

Comment: Of course all kinds of stuff may get broken when you put the word `unsafe` in your code!

Comment: There's a wrong assumption as well: the halting problem does *not* state that you can't detect non-termination, it just says that you can't do that for *every* program. Your `isUndefined` function will definitely not terminate on all possible values of `x`

Comment: Yes `undefined` in GHC is "broken" but it's broken in a good way. Implementing `undefined` this way is semantically equivalent in 99% of cases and if you use an `unsafe*` function your already crossing into dark magic

Comment: Which version are you using? This doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: @AndrewC: Sorry this was more of a theoretical question and I didn't test the code before submitting it, it was just an idea. I've edited it so that it should now compile on GHC 7.6.3.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to make three, [ah, no](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqreRufrkxM), four (interrelated) points.

1. **No, using `unsafe...` doesn't count:**

   Using `unsafeCoerce` is clearly a rule-breaking move, so to answer the question "Does this really count?": no, it doesn't count. `unsafe` is the warning that all sorts of stuff breaks, including semantics:

   ```
   isGood :: a -> Bool
   isGood x = unsafePerformIO . fmap read $ readFile "I_feel_like_it.txt"
   ```

   ```
   > isGood '4'
   True
   > isGood '4'
   False
   ```

   Yikes! Broken semantics according to the Haskell report. Oh, no, wait, I used `unsafe...`. I was warned.

   The main problem is using `unsafeCoerce`, with which you can turn anything into anything else. It's as bad as typecasts in imperative programming, so all type safety has gone out of the window.
2. **You're `catch`ing an IOException, not a pure error (⊥).**

   To use catch, you've converted the pure error `undefined` to an IO Exception. The `IO` monad is deceptively simple, and the error handling semantics don't require the use of ⊥. Think of it as like a monad transformer including an error-handling `Either` at some level.
3. **The link with the halting problem is completely spurious**

   We don't need any unsafe features of any programming language to cause *this* sort of distinguishing between non-termination and error.

   Imagine two programs. One program `Char -> IO ()` that outputs the character, the other which writes the output of the first to a file, then compares that file with the string `"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined"`, and finds its length. We can run the first one with input `undefined` or with input `'c'`. The first is ⊥, the second is normal termination.

   Yikes! We've solved the halting problem by distinguishing between undefined and non-termination. Oh no, wait, no, we've actually only distinguished between `undefined` and termination. If we run the two programs on the input `non_terminating where non_terminating = head.show.length $ [1..]`, we find the second one doesn't terminate, because the first one doesn't. In fact our second program *fails* to solve the halting problem, because it itself does not terminate.

   A solution to the halting problem would be more like having a **total** function `halts :: (a -> IO ()) -> a -> Bool` that **always** terminates with the output `True` if the given function terminates with input `a`, and `False` if it never terminates. You're impossibly far from that when you distinguish between `undefined` and `error "user-defined error"`, which is what your code does.

   Thus all your references to the halting problem are confusing deciding whether **one** program terminates with deciding whether **any** program terminates. It fails to draw any conclusion if you use the input `non-terminating` above instead of `undefined`; it's already a big stretch semantically to call that distinguishing between non-termination and `undefined`, and it's nonsense to call it a solution to the halting problem.
4. **The problem isn't a huge semantic issue**

   Essentially all your code is able to do is determine whether your error value was produced using `undefined` or some other error producing function. The semantic issue there is that both `undefined` and `error "not defined with undefined"` have the semantic value ⊥, but you can distinguish between them. OK, that's not very clean theoretically, but having different outputs on different causes for ⊥ is **so** useful for debugging that it'd be crazy to enforce a common response to the value ⊥, because it would have to be always non-termination to be completely correct.

   The result would be that any program with any bug would be obliged to go into an infinite output-free loop when it had an error. This is taking theoretical niceness to the point of deep unhelpfulness. Much better is to print `*** Exception: Prelude.undefined` or `Error: ungrokable wibbles` or other helpful, descriptive error messages.

   To be at all helpful in a crisis, any programming language has to sacrifice your desire to have every ⊥ behave the same as each other. Distinguishing between different ⊥s isn't theoretically lovely, but it would stupid to not do this in practice.

   If a programming language theorist calls that a severe semantic problem, they should be teased for living in a world where program-freeze/non-termination is always the best outcome for invalid input.

Answer (score 6):

From [the docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Unsafe-Coerce.html):

> The highly unsafe primitive `unsafeCoerce` converts a value from any type to any other type. Needless to say, if you use this function, it is your responsibility to ensure that the old and new types have identical internal representations, in order to prevent runtime corruption.

It obviously also breaks referential transparency, thus *pureness*, so you give up all the guarantees that the Haskell semantics give you.

There are lots of ways to shoot yourself in the foot as soon as you leave pure terrain. You could just as well use OS primitives to read your whole process memory in `IO`, breaking referential transparency in the worst kind of way.

Apart from that,, your definition of `isUndefined` does *not* solve the halting problem, because it's not *total*, which means that it doesn't terminate on all inputs.

For example, `isUndefined (last [1..])` will not terminate.

There are lots of programs for which we can prove that they do or do not terminate, but that doesn't mean we have solved the halting problem.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not a crank, in no way to I claim to have solved the halting problem :) I fully understand why this code does not solve the halting problem.

My point is that this is a _severe_ break with Haskell's formal semantics. Other unsafe functions break referential transparency. Which is "bad", but not as "bad" as this.

Comment: @Julian: So what is the break in semantics then? I thought your argument was that you can write a function that detects non-termination (which you obviously cannot). `undefined` is just one specific example of non-termination that is easy to detect in the `IO` monad, if you want to interpret it as such

Comment: The formal semantics of Haskell say that undefined subsumes termination, so a value of undefined should be in a sense undistinguishable from non-termination. However inside the unsafe part of the GHC implementation of the language, this is possible. This is a break with the semantics which is presumably an unintentional side effect of the other unsafe functions which are themselves added for convenience.

Comment: @Julien: What is your first sentence based on ("bottom subsumes non-termination")? Is this part of the Haskell standard?

Comment: Found it: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch1.html#x6-120001.3 So then the correct answer to your question is: `unsafeCoerce` is not part of safe Haskell, so you can only catch errors in `IO`

Comment: That was quick :)
Sorry I poorly defined my question, my point is, this is a rather severe break with the formal semantics and although it is an unintended side effect of "good" breaks, is it a step to far, I was wondering what people though :)

Comment: @Julian: In fact, you can write no such `isUndefined` function unless you can find a bug in Haskell's type system or resort to non-safe functions (by doing which you give up all guarantees). So basically, I don't see the problem... What would be a problem if this could be done in [Safe Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html), which would indicate some kind of bug

Comment: I guess that's fair enough.

My point was even for "unsafe" Haskell this is seemed to be (in my opinion) a massive break with the formal specification and I was wondering what people thought about it.

Comment: @JulianSutherland No, the break is only massive if you start talking it up by spuriously linking it with the halting problem. The main problem is using `unsafeCoerce` with which you can turn anything into anything else. It's as bad as typecasts in imperative programming, so all type safety has gone out of the window, and it's nothing to do with the halting problem.

Comment: @AndrewC: I don't believe the link is spurious, the formal specification says undefined must be indistinguishable from non termination. So if the formal specification where to be followed to the letter (which it is not in unsafe Haskell) then a function that could verify undefinedness would be equivalent to a halting oracle. I am not saying that the language is broken, simply that unsafe Haskell breaks from the formal specification in ways that I certainly found unexpected and that a programming language theorist would certainly call "severe"

Comment: @JulianSutherland Actually, the report says _Errors in Haskell are semantically equivalent to ⊥ (“bottom”). Technically, they are indistinguishable from nontermination, so the language includes no mechanism for detecting or acting upon errors. However, implementations will probably try to provide useful information about errors._ Your function doesn't distinguish between non-termination and undefined, mainly because it doesn't terminate on non-terminating input like `isUndefined (let xs = xs ++ xs in xs`! (If you count that, then you'd better raise the alarm on the  `id` function's semantics!)